# How do I return http output from a sub-function in azure function

Tags: node.js, function, azure, callback

I am working on an Azure function to return an entity from a Cosmos DB table. I'm providing all of the required inputs in the function initially for the purposes of testing but can't get the http response from the function.

I'm not a developer but need to get this set up for the purposes of testing some infrastructure, please pardon my lack of knowledge possibly of some fundamental rules.

```
    var storage = require('azure-storage');
    var storageClient = storage.createTableService();
    module.exports = async function (context, req, callback) {
    storageClient.retrieveEntity('tablename', 'partitionkey', 'rowkey', function (error, result) {
        if (error) {
            console.log("error");
        } else context.res = {
            body: result,
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }  
        }
        context.done()
        })
    };
```

I can output the result using console.log but can't get any http response.
I've tried a few different variations of what is contained in context.res but I think it is not going to be outputted from where it is placed in the function, but moving it outside the function doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to return the output using a promise function;

await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {